# Set niceness to piped command

Tags: nice

I need to execute a set of "piped" commands with altered niceness level. Example:

```
nice -n 15 command1 | command2 | command3
```

In this case niceness is altered to "15" only for command1. How to change it for the whole set of commands (command1, command2 and command3)?

Answer (score 19):

```
 nice -n 15 sh -c "command1 | command2 | command3"
```

This sets niceness of a subshell, and the commands 1..3 inherit it.

Answer (score 13):

```
nice -n 15 command1 | nice -n <num> command2 | nice -n <num> command3
```

`nice` isn't used differently from any other command.

Answer (score 0):

`exec command{1..26}` runs all commands numbered 'command1' all the way to 'command26'

`nice -n 15 $(pgrep command)`   renices any running process with 'command' in it

Comment: `command` is very likely just a place holder.

Comment: I think there is a "race" condition here in that if any of the commands forks or starts another process, that one won't get picked up when changing the niceness. The other two answers set niceness at start so new processes will inherit that value